# Send Mp3 file as attachment in email from a URL ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, mp3, email-attachments

I need to send a mp3 file as an email attachment in my .Net Application. The file itself is not on my server but is on a remote url. What can be best methodology for that? Do i need to download file on my server first and then attach it with an email or i can directly attach it without downloading? How to achieve this

Comment: Please clarify: isn't providing a link in the email (so the end user could download the file) good enough?
If not - you'll have to first download the file.

Comment: what about attaching that file through memory stream containing mp3 file?